# Why can't I do this - Create a .net object and call one method all on one line

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
(New clsViewIllus).View(MyIBaseView, enumViewSolveTypes.View, Me, , True)
```

... in VB? Basically too lazy to do this:

```
Dim vi As New clsViewIllus
vi.View(MyIBaseView, enumViewSolveTypes.View, Me, , True)
```

Comment: Because if you want to that, then you should make clsViewIllus a shared class.

Comment: You have a class called clsViewIllus? Really? :)

Comment: @IAbstract - Good point. It is a presenter in MVP program and sometimes I've seen these being shared or modules. As you can guess by the view coming in as a parameter it's a pretty stateless class. However re-looking the class has other uses and ways to use the methods; this is just the default/typical way.

Comment: @Jamie: VB.Net seems to inherently force H-notation because of it's case-insensitivity. I see a lot of VB'ers doing this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the post is back in 2011, but a helpful tip for those who come across this post...

You can also use the Call statement, such as:

```
Call New clsViewIllus.View(MyIBaseView, enumViewSolveTypes.View, Me, , True)
```

You can even set properties along the way...

```
Call New clsViewIllus With {.Prop1 = value}.View(MyIBaseView, enumViewSolveTypes.View, Me, , True)
```

Comment: I looked up this question I remembered I'd asked ... and saw this answer! This worked - Await Task.Run(Sub() Call (New UpgradeNum).SetTitleText()) - although other examples might be more explanatory..

Answer (score 1):

`clsViewIllus` should be a shared class. You mentioned in comments that the class has *other uses and ways to use the methods*. But do those *other uses* stay in context with the method you have defined?

If not, then you need to write another class.

Now, to your question:

*Why can't I*:

```
(New clsViewIllus).View(MyIBaseView, enumViewSolveTypes.View, Me, , True)
```

**Edit**
<strike>Basically, it isn't allowed from what I can tell. If I can find something in the language specification, I will update. But the compiler pretty much tells you why this can't be done:</strike>

I made a mistake on my side:

I believe you can. I did it in C#. What you may be missing is the parentheses. Try this:

```
(New clsViewIllus()).View(MyIBaseView, enumViewSolveTypes.View, Me, , True)
```

Although, IMHO, it is bad form and screams for `Module` or `Shared`.

Comment: "do those other uses stay in context with the method you have defined?" - Probably not ;-)  But if I'm too lazy to spend 2 lines of code, I'm _definitely_ two lazy to refactor anything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've found, with vs2008, It can't be done, unless you do something with the return value, e.g.,:

`Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo("c:\temp\out.bmp") With {.UseShellExecute = True})`

but my .View above is a sub so I couldn't even assign it to a dummy object. Makes sense that you can do this in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Hack Version

```
CType(New clsViewIllus(), clsViewIllus).View(MyIBaseView,....)
```